# RoomDatabase_Impl does not exist

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-architecture-components

I when try to implement a Room Database, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.Database.HilarityUserDatabase. HilarityUserDatabase_Impl does not exist
                                                 at android.arch.persistence.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:92)
```

I tried adding the relevant kotlin dependencies to my gradle file (shown below) but when I do, all of my Databinding classes that would normally be generated with any issues are now generating errors in my gradle console. Is there way for me to use the DataBinding library and the Room Pesistence Library?

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
...
dependencies{
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 22):

It did happen to me before, make sure that you have all 3 dependencies in build.gradle

```
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor  'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
kapt 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
```

Also, a "Project Clean" after gradle synch will help as well.

Comment: I use all except this: kapt 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
and work fine, and I used the version 1.1.1 thx

Comment: `kapt` is for Kotlin. You must use `annotationProcessor ` for Java.

Comment: To add kapt you need add too the `kapt` plugin at start of your gradle file `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

Answer (score 14):

Make sure **kotlin-kapt** is included in app-level gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and make sure you use **kapt** instead of **annotationProcessor**. That solved my problem.

And also check Room Model, DAO, and Database files for @Entity, @Dao and @Database annotations.

Comment: adding `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` Helped me

Comment: I was missing the @Database annotation. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

For usage of Room, LiveData and ViewModel you need these libraries:

`•implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0" 
•implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
•kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
•kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"`

LiveData and ViewModel allows you to use the DataBinding technique.

For more info check the official page: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html

Comment: this dint help for me

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, later found that I am not using the @Database annotation for AppDatabase

Use this

`@Database(entities = {RowEntity.class, WifiDetailEntity.class}, version = 1)`

`public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase`

`{ ...`

Answer (score 0):

For the newer version of the room compiler don't need to add both dependencies, Just do the following -

```
kapt 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:2.2.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained above, for ease

1- Add the following in the build.gradle(Module:app) at the very top of the file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

2- Then add

```
//Room for database
def room_version = "2.2.5"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
kapt 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
```

3- Sync the file and clean the project. Done

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem while doing Codelabs. I was able to solve it by adding the updated Room dependencies on my build.gradle(module).

You can copy and paste the implementation declarations from the Room docs page in the Android Developer site. (Note: Check in your list of dependencies for

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5'
```

or similar, make sure to remove it and only leave the one you copied and pasted, which would look like this

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
```

)

[Room | Android Developers #Declaring Dependencies](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#declaring_dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Add these Dependencies to your build.gradle file

```
  implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
  annotationProcessor  'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
  kapt 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
```

> MhzDev answer is fine these are the updated version of the dependencies